# How to change the cursor to a watch in GTK for C?

Tags: c, gtk, mouse-cursor

I'm using the C-style GTK functions in C++ and I can't figure out how to set the cursor for the main window.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `gdk_set_cursor()`

(https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#gdk-window-set-cursor)

on a GdkCursor created by `gdk_cursor_new()`

(https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Cursors.html)

Comment: yes I figured that out but the problem is I can't get the gdkwindow of my main window. I've seen samples for gtkmm and for pygtk but not for C

Answer (score 6):

Use [`gdk_window_set_cursor()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#gdk-window-set-cursor) on a GdkCursor created by [`gdk_cursor_new_from_name()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Cursors.html#gdk-cursor-new-from-name).

To get the GdkWindow of a GtkWindow you can use [`gtk_widget_get_window()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-window) because GtkWindow is a subclass of GtkWidget.

Note: this answer is an improvement over [idefixs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10261523/258462) (important correction + link update + minor modification to make the answer complete + improved formatting) that was rejected as an edit.

Answer (score 5):

Posting this because the comment about getting the GdkWndow went unanswered so far.

For most widgets, the GdkWindow can be retrieved as the window data field of the GtkWidget structure. The following code sets a cursor on a GtkWindow widget:

```
GtkWidget* win = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
GdkCursor* watchCursor = gdk_cursor_new(GDK_WATCH);

/* set watch cursor */
gdk_window_set_cursor(win->window, watchCursor);

/* return to normal */
gdk_window_set_cursor(win->window, NULL);
```

If you need to get to the GtkWindow ancestor from one of its child widgets, you can use:

```
GtkWidget* win = gtk_widget_get_ancestor(someWidget, GTK_TYPE_WINDOW);
```

Comment: [gtk_widget_get_window()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-window) should be used. GTK+ 3 has no such field; all fields of `Widget` are private, quite rightly.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
void gtkSetCursor(GdkCursorType cursorType) {
    GdkScreen * screen = gdk_screen_get_default();
    GdkWindow * win = gdk_screen_get_root_window(screen);
    GdkCursor * cursor = gdk_cursor_new(cursorType); //http://developer.gimp.org/api/2.0/gdk/gdk-Cursors.html
    gdk_window_set_cursor(win, cursor);
    while (gtk_events_pending()) gtk_main_iteration();
}

...
gtkSetCursor(GDK_WATCH);
start your stuff here
...
end of your stuff
gtkSetCursor(GDK_LEFT_PTR);
```

Answer (score 0):

jeff's answer didn't work for me (Gtk3). So here's my solution:

```
GdkWindow* win = gtk_widget_get_parent_window(widget);
GdkCursor* watchCursor = gdk_cursor_new(GDK_WATCH);
gdk_window_set_cursor(win, watchCursor);
```